# Replace with a text while encountering onError on Image REACT NATIVE

Tags: image, react-native

Just like HTML, we have the opportunity to show a text i.e. 
`<img src="hello.png" alt="hello" />`

There is plenty of suggestions for replacing an image with another image (fallback src), but I need to show a text instead of any other images!

Comment: are you fetching image from api?

Comment: yes, just on not being able to fetch the image , I need to display the text only!

Answer (score 0):

[React Native Image onError](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#onerror) method will execute on Image when image not found on server or unexpectedly something wrong goes with the connection. Using that you can display text as below,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default class Example extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoadingImage: true,
    isImageFailed: false
  };

  onErrorLoadingImage = () => {
    this.setState({
      isLoadingImage: false,
      isImageFailed: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {!this.state.isImageFailed ? (
          <Image
            source={{
              uri:
                "https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Guitar.jpg"
            }}
            style={styles.imageStyle}
            onError={this.onErrorLoadingImage}
          />
        ) : (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Error loading image</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  imageStyle: {
    resizeMode: "center",
    width: "50%",
    height: "50%"
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, there is no other way to display text just like HTML `alt=" Error loading image "`

Hope this will help you.